# How did (Disney's) Tinker Bell meet up with that version of Peter Pan?

Tags: peter-pan, tinker-bell, tinker-bell-2008

In most versions of J.M. Barrie's tale, *Peter and Wendy*, the guardian fairy Tinker Bell is Peter's aide de camp, as well as constant companion. The Disney version of the character, however, expanded her story greatly, giving her several films, friends, a sister, and adventures all of her own...

[image]

[image]

Originally, I thought Tinker Bell was the fairy born of Peter's first laugh, hence why she was so attached to him. The aforementioned series, however, proves that not to be the case.

How then did Tinker Bell become the personal Fairy of the boy Prince of Neverland?

And at what point (as in how long before his adventure meeting Wendy, John, and Michael) did she join him?

Comment: The 2008 film series doesn't contain Peter at all. It would appear that she met him afterwards, which isn't surprising since the show was considered to be a "prequel" to *Peter Pan* and its sequel

Comment: Note that in Barrie's novel Peter specifically refutes Tinkerbell being the fairy born from his laugh - he tells her it is impossible, as he is male and she is female.

Comment: @Showsni Been years since I read the novel, but I _vaguely_ remember something like that. Still, that makes even _less_ sense then as to why Tink is so ... I don't know, particularly possessive, I guess....when it comes to Peter.

Comment: @Showsni - Right, but Peter is a bit of a blusterer and knows rather less than he likes to claim. Doesn't he also think that girls have cooties or something roughly along those lines? I would not take his statements as definitive.

Comment: @Showsni plus we also learn that fairies are very short-lived, and Peter's -- him being long-lived, even though he won't grow up -- cannot still have his original fairy around. Of course, Disney's Tinkerbell isn't short-lived at all, one of many changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sticking strictly to the Disney version of events, we learn of Tinkerbell and Peter's first meeting in the [Disney Fairies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disney_Fairies) tie-in novel [*The Trouble with Tink*](https://disneyfairies.fandom.com/wiki/The_Trouble_with_Tink). There's no specific timescale given other than that it happened after the events of the Fairies films, presumably to stop them painting themselves into a corner if they decide to continue making Fairies-branded [Tinker Bell films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disney_Fairies#Films)

> “A shark’s tooth,” Peter replied, just a bit smugly. “Isn’t it swell?
> I’m going to put it on a string and make a necklace.”
>
> “The first time I met Peter, he was trying to steal a shark’s tooth,”
> Tink explained to Terence.
>
> “That’s right!” exclaimed Peter. “I’d made a bet with the boys that I
> could steal a tooth from a live shark. I built a small raft out of
> birchwood and was paddling out to sea…”
>
> From the way he began, Terence could tell that Peter had told this
> story many times before, and that he loved telling it.
>
> “I had just paddled beyond the reef,” Peter continued, “when I felt
> something bump the underside of my raft.”
>
> “The shark?” asked Terence.
>
> Peter nodded. “He was looking for his lunch. But he didn’t know that I
> was looking for him, too!”
>
> “How did you plan to get his tooth?” Terence asked.
>
> “I meant to stun him with my oar, then steal the tooth while he was
> out cold,” said Peter. “But he was bigger than I’d thought, and before
> I knew it, he’d bitten my little raft right in half! I was sinking
> fast, and it looked like the end for me, when suddenly I heard a
> jingling sound over my head. I looked up and there was Tinker Bell.
> She yelled down at me…”
>
> “‘Fly, silly boy!’” Tink and Peter cried together. They laughed,
> remembering.
>
> “But I didn’t know how to fly,” Peter told Terence. “So Tink taught me
> how, right then and there. She sprinkled some fairy dust on me, and
> before I knew it, I’d zipped up into the air, out of the shark’s
> reach. Boy, was he mad!”

Comment: Yes, it was the Disney version I was referring to, as it's not quite consistent with Barrie's original canon. The Fox **Peter PAn and the Pirates** version implied that PEter had been essentially raised, at least partly, by the fairies and was well regarded by King Oberon and Queen Titania. This is a little anti-climactic, but answers it perfectly; thanks V.